# Callback from API

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have the following script on `http://foobar.com/api?callback=mycallback`:

```
var something = 'aaa';
var callback = mycallback;
(function() {
   var output = eval(something);
   callback(output);
});
```

And I want to access this script from my own script, and fetch the output. So I am doing the following:

```
var module1 = (function() {
   var getFromApi = function(output) {
      return (function(output) {
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.setAttribute('src', 'http://foobar.com/api?callback=mycallback');
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      });
   };
   var fetch = function() {
      getFromApi(function(output) {
         console.log(output);
      });
   };
   return {
      fetch: fetch
   };
})();

module1.fetch();
```

The result should be the output from this script, but it is not, it doesn't even enters the callback. How can I do this properly?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is `jsonp` URL?

Comment: [Here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/getting-data-across-domains-jsonp) is good read, how `jsonp` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in module1:

- getFromApi returns a function (let's call it fn)
- fn has a parameter named output that shadows the argument of the outer function making the argument passed to getFromApi useless
- fetch calls getFromApi and it does nothing else
- the callback function must be globally accessible

A possible solution could be:

```
var module1 = (function() {
var getFromApi = function(output) {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.setAttribute('src', 'http://foobar.com/api?callback='+output);
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};
var fetch = function() {
  getFromApi('myfunction');
};
return {
  fetch: fetch
};
})();
function myfunction(output) {
     console.log(output);
}
module1.fetch();
```

Possible nasty solution for function as callback (It will not work in IE but can be adapted)

```
var module1 = (function() {
  var getFromApi = function(output) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://foobar.com/api?callback=eval(document.currentScript.dataset.fn)');
    script.setAttribute('data-fn', '(function(){ return ' + output +'})()');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
  var fetch = function() {
    return getFromApi(function(output){
      console.log(output);
      /*remember to remove script tag*/
      document.currentScript.remove();
    });
  };
  return {
    fetch: fetch
  };
})();
module1.fetch();
```

Comment: But `output` variable is undefined here. And is not a function.

Comment: Which output is undefined?

Comment: I mean, callback variable inside the API is now a function, but all brackets are converted to special characters, and I'm getting unexpected `%`

Comment: You need to decode the callback parameter (I took for granted it was done automatically) if you can modify the script, otherwise i'll edit the answer for a js solution